# Website redirect, 301 redirection

Tags: .htaccess

Live site- http://www.marchingmonk.com

When you click on the "home" button of the website, the user is not being redirected to http://www.marchingmonk.com, the user is redirected to http://www.marchingmonk.com/home, this creating a duplicate content issue.

Any idea how to fix that issue by making a 301 redirection

Comment: If you don’t want the link to point to `/home`, but `/` instead – then why don’t you just write the latter into the `href` attribute of the link in the first place …?

Answer (score 0):

You fix by adding this to your htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /home /
```

And if you can, change the "home" link to just point to `/`.